# swift ios add infinite scroll pagination to uitableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, infinite-scroll

I wonder if tableview has any built-in function to add infinite scroll/pagination.

Right now my VC looks like this:

```
var data: JSON! = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Init start height of cell
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 122
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self

    savedLoader.startAnimation()
    //Load first page
    loadSaved(1)

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("aCell") as! SavedTableViewCell

    let info = data[indexPath.row]
    cell.configureWithData(info)

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("WebSegue", sender: indexPath)

    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
}
```

I fetch my data using **loadSaved(1)** by giving the function the current page I want to load. The function makes a API request using alomofire then populate the **var data: JSON! = []** with the data that should be displayed

So what I want to do is when I scroll to the bottom of the tableview **loadSaved(2)** should be called loading more data into the tableview

Comment: My answer here can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28246394/showing-cells-in-demands-in-uicollectionview-with-vertical-infinite-scroll

Comment: https://github.com/canopas/MarqueeScroll

Answer (score 29):

Looks like [amar’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54457661/882630) might be a better solution now, but here’s my answer from 2017 anyway:

The UITableViewDelegate has a [table​View(_:​will​Display:​for​Row​At:​) instance method](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614883-tableview) which "tells the delegate the table view is about to draw a cell for a particular row."

In your case I would use it something like this:

```
override open func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == data.count-1 { //you might decide to load sooner than -1 I guess...
      //load more into data here
    }
}
```

Depending on your code, you may need some checks around this to ensure you don't end up in an infinite loop if you've loaded all your data...

Comment: I tried this method on swift 5 and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @Ste did you try amar’s answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54457661/882630

Answer (score 7):

No, the `UITableView` has not any built-in function to achieve the infinite scroll or load *on-demand* cells like you want. What you can use is the function [`scrollViewDidScroll(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidScroll:) in the `UIScrollViewDelegate` implemented by default in the `UITableView` and in this way know when the user scroll more than the original height defined in the `UITableView`.

For example like in this code:

```
var indexOfPageToRequest = 1

override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    // calculates where the user is in the y-axis
    let offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let contentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height

    if offsetY > contentHeight - scrollView.frame.size.height {

        // increments the number of the page to request
        indexOfPageToRequest += 1

        // call your API for more data
        loadSaved(indexOfPageToRequest)

        // tell the table view to reload with the new data
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

To achieve the result of add the rest of the elements at the end of the `UITableView` you should add the new elements to the data source, in your case `data` inside your function `loadSaved(numberOfPage)`.

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 6):

All the above answers are correct but for iOS 10 and above we have a very nice

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, prefetchRowsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath])
```

This is a  prefetch delegate which needs to be set

```
tableView.prefetchDataSource = self
```

[RayWeinderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5786-uitableview-infinite-scrolling-tutorial) has a nice tutorial on the topic. Since Rays is a dependable site i am not posting code here

Answer (score 4):

I have modified Victor's answer and used it as ,

```
var indexOfPageRequest = 1
var loadingStatus = false

func loadData(){
    if !loadingStatus{
        loadingStatus = true
        viewModel.getData(pageIndex: indexOfPageRequest)
    }
}

override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    // calculates where the user is in the y-axis
    let offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let contentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height

    if offsetY > contentHeight - scrollView.frame.size.height {

        // increments the number of the page to request
        indexOfPageRequest += 1

        // call your API for more data
        loadData()

        // tell the table view to reload with the new data
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Reset loadingStatus to true when you receive data. Without checking if the view was already loading more data, the tableview was flickering.

Comment: what if our tableview does not start from top, but from bottom? how can I make this kind of check at that case?

Comment: This way is more cpu consuming. It's better to check at which row is the user, then where he scrolled.

Answer (score 2):

Ravi's answer looks good. But as he pointed out in the end, the tableView **flickers** a lot if you use `scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)`

This is because you are trying to reload tableView every time you are scrolling the tableView.

Instead you could use  `scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool)` delegate method to determine whether you have scrolled enough and have reached almost the end of the tableView.

```
override func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {

    let offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        let contentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height

        if offsetY > contentHeight - scrollView.frame.size.height {
               indexOfPageRequest += 1
               loadData()
               self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Above Ans are also right, but may be some one help out this code also.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    if(indexPath.row == self.arryOfData.count-1){
        if(self.pageNumber <= self.resPgNumber){
            if(remaining != 0){
                let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
                spinner.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: tableView.bounds.width, height: CGFloat(44))
                spinner.startAnimating()
                tableView.tableFooterView = spinner
                tableView.tableFooterView?.isHidden = false

                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                    self.flgActivity = false
                    self.getActiveOrdersList()
                }
            }
            else{
                tableView.tableFooterView?.removeFromSuperview()
                let view = UIView()
                view.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: tableView.bounds.width, height: CGFloat(5))
                tableView.tableFooterView = view
                tableView.tableFooterView?.isHidden = true
            }
        }
        else{
            tableView.tableFooterView?.removeFromSuperview()
            let view = UIView()
            view.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: tableView.bounds.width, height: CGFloat(5))
            tableView.tableFooterView = view
            tableView.tableFooterView?.isHidden = true
        }
    }
    else{
        tableView.tableFooterView?.removeFromSuperview()
        let view = UIView()
        view.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: tableView.bounds.width, height: CGFloat(5))
        tableView.tableFooterView = view
        tableView.tableFooterView?.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the way you are checking the row that should be shown, but why you are adding hidden view on 3 places with the same code?

Answer (score 0):

There are number of ways we can do this. The essense of all different ways, is to load next set of data when user scroll to last. I have implemented it via adding an extra special cell at the end of tableView and when that cell gets loaded in *`willDisplay cell: forRowAtIndexPath:`* which triggers next set of fetching of data.

Athough this is simple to implement but in larger apps at times we need to implement it many places. To avoid this, I wrote a small [framework](https://github.com/mrigankgupta/Pageable) which is non-intrusive and can be easyly integrated.